# LeetCode - 203. Remove Linked list element. could you explain why my solution is not working please?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I found the answer which uses the similar approach I am using.
This is the correct answer.

```
    public static ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
    ListNode temp = new ListNode(0);
    temp.next = head;
    ListNode prev = temp;
    while(head != null) {
        if(head.val == val) {
            prev.next = head.next;
        }
        else {
            prev = head;
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    return temp.next;  
}
```

And I'll show you my answer first.

```
    public static ListNode removeElements_wrong(ListNode head, int val) {
    ListNode prev = new ListNode(0);
    prev.next = head;
    while(head != null) {
        if(head.val == val) {
            prev.next = head.next;
        }
        else {
            prev = head;
        }
        head = head.next;
    }
    return prev;  
}
```

When the inputs are  [1,2,6,3,4,5,6], 6. output is [5]
I see the differences is above the while loop and return statement. I directly set

```
ListNode prev = new ListNode(0);
prev.next = head;
```

But the correct solution has

```
ListNode temp = new ListNode(0);
temp.next = head;
ListNode prev = temp;
```

I don't understand why I need to use temp, how is it working and why can't I just set ListNode pre = 0 and pre.next=head. Then return prev?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of the `prev` in the `temp` variable because you are modifying the `prev` inside the while loop and lost the first state when temp and prev were pointing to.

As you noticed the `temp` is declared with a dummy node so when return just call `temp.next`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and diagram. I understand that prev gets modified in while loop so I couldn't get the desirable answer when I return prev. But how come temp.next return the correct answer(a filtered list)? I set LN temp = 0 in the beginning. And temp.next = head. But head is also modified in the while loop, isn't it?(head=head.next)

Comment: The idea is to keep a reference to the beginning of `LinkedList`, and in the `while` loop you modify the `head` and `prev`, and when the loop is finished you have the pointer to the beginning of the `LinkedList`. As digram shows it refers to node `0` and head (so we return `temp.next`)

Comment: as you know in the `while` loop you keep a pointer to the previous node and the current node. Then check if the current node contains the value which I want to delete then connect the `prev.next = head.next`

Comment: And good advice when dealing with `LinkedList` just gets a paper, draw the nodes and perform the delete to develop better visualization of it :)

Comment: If you happy with the answer, could you approve that :)

Comment: yeah I think now I have a better understanding of it. Thank you so much. and I really appreciate quick reply.